# NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver and TimeInterval rounding more than 7 decimal places

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I encountered a problem when working with NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver.

I need to archive the dictionary `["updated": time, "isFavorite": true]`, where time is the time Interval since 1970.

My code looks like this:

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    /** Decode data and returns Dictionary<String,Any>, use NSKeyedUnarchiver decoder */
    var decode: [String:Any]?  {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: self) as? [String:Any]
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {
    /** Encode  Dictionary<String,Any> to the data, use NSKeyedUnarchiver encoder */
    var encode: Data? {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    }
}

/** The current time since 1970 */
var time: Double {
    return Date().timeIntervalSince1970   // example 1491800604.362141
}

//////TEST
let payload: Dictionary<String,Any> = ["updated": time, "isFavorite": true]

print("Data before archiving: \(payload)")

let encodePayload = payload.encode
let decodePayload = encodePayload?.decode

print("Data after unarchive: \(decodePayload!)")
```

All works well if the time variable contains <= 6 decimal places, but i get >= 7 decimal places digit and  is **rounded**.

Example Correctly

- Data before archiving: ["updated": 1522537700.**689399**,
  "isFavorite": true]
- Data after unarchive: ["updated":
  1522537700.**689399**, "isFavorite": 1]

Example Not correct

- Data before archiving: ["updated": 1522536585.**2104979**,
  "isFavorite": true]
- Data after unarchive: ["updated":
  1522536585.**210498**, "isFavorite": 1]

Comment: A `Double` is good for about 15 or 16 significant digits. The number of decimal places is irrelevant. Your numbers are at that limit.

Comment: Yes, I do not crash in XCODE, but the API to which I transmit information can not accept it because it is important for it to get the value before the millisecond.

Comment: I didn't say anything about crashing. I'm explaining why the number is being rounded. The number `1522536585.2104979,` is 17 digits. That's too many digits for a `Double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rmaddy pointed out, this is a limitation of the precision of the `Double` type:

```
let payload: Dictionary<String,Any> = ["updated": 1522536585.2104979 as Double, "isFavorite": true]

print("Data before archiving: \(payload)")

let encodePayload = payload.encode
let decodePayload = encodePayload?.decode

print("Data after unarchive: \(decodePayload!)")
```

outputs:

```
Data before archiving: ["updated": 1522536585.2104979, "isFavorite": true]
Data after unarchive: ["updated": 1522536585.210498, "isFavorite": 1]
```

However, you can archive things with greater precision using `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
let decimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 15225365852104979, exponent: -7, isNegative: false)

let payload: Dictionary<String,Any> = ["updated": decimalNumber, "isFavorite": true]

print("Data before archiving: \(payload.description)")

let encodePayload = payload.encode
let decodePayload = encodePayload?.decode

print("Data after unarchive: \(decodePayload!.description)")
```

outputs:

```
Data before archiving: ["updated": 1522536585.2104979, "isFavorite": true]
Data after unarchive: ["updated": 1522536585.2104979, "isFavorite": 1]
```

You can also use the Swift-native `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber`, but its initializer is, for some reason, very poorly documented and much more awkward to use:

```
// If you ever end up compiling for a big-endian architecture,
// the byte ordering here may need to be reversed.
// Of course it's not possible to test whether that's actually true at present.
let decimal = Decimal(_exponent: -7, _length: 56, _isNegative: 0, _isCompact: 0, _reserved: 0, _mantissa: (0xa913, 0xbb30, 0x1763, 0x0036, 0, 0, 0, 0))

let payload: Dictionary<String,Any> = ["updated": decimal, "isFavorite": true]

print("Data before archiving: \(payload.description)")

let encodePayload = payload.encode
let decodePayload = encodePayload?.decode

print("Data after unarchive: \(decodePayload!.description)")
```

outputs:

```
Data before archiving: ["updated": 1522536585.2104979, "isFavorite": true]
Data after unarchive: ["updated": 1522536585.2104979, "isFavorite": 1]
```

Comment: Yes the variant using Decimal is suitable for solving my problem, thanks!